# How to call Html.ActionLink in Partial View?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

My structure of Controllers and Views is as follow

```
Controller
         |_Disorders
         |         |_Anxiety
         |                  |_AnxietyController
         | HomeController



 Views
        |_Anxiety
        |        |_Anxiety.aspx
        |_Home
             |_Index.aspx
```

I am trying to call this from partial view which is located as follow:

```
Views
     |_Shared
     |        |_Header.ascx // header is included in Site.Master
     |
     |Site.Master
```

I am putting this code in Header.ascx

```
<li><% Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home"); %></li>
<li><% Html.ActionLink("Anxiety", "Anxiety", "Anxiety"); %></li>
```

I have followed this `Html.ActionLink(linktext, Actionname, controllername)` but unable to fix it.

Its in `MVC3`

Comment: Is this a pure `asp.net mvc` application? If so, why do you have `*.ascx` files at all?

Comment: Yes this is `asp.net mvc 3 web application` and i am just including `partial views` @ovm

Comment: `ascx` is the extension for classic asp.net `UserControls`. There is a legacy support for those files but this is not the recommended approach to implement partial views.

Comment: I just wanted to separate my code layers so included partial views.. @ovm

Comment: Its not even working in Site.Master if i include it directly ? @ovm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The controller param isn't a path. It's just the name of the controller, i.e. `_Anxiety` based on your class of `_AnxietyController`. (The `Controller` bit is left off intentionally. That is how the helper expects it. It knows all your controllers end in `Controller`.)

Comment: What is the problem with the home ?

Comment: check my updated question its not even working in this case ?

Comment: There shouldn't be a problem with creating the link to your HomeController.Index action, based on what you've posted. However, there *will* be an exception raised while rendering the view once you actually follow the link, unless you've explicitly returned the full path to the view. By convention, Razor will look for a template in `Views\Home`, not `Views\_Home`. In general, you should just get rid of all these underscores. They don't add anything (in fact they detract from meaning as an underscore is only really used for partial views).

Comment: the problem was `:` I was not putting this in `<% Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home"); %>` but still other issue for anxiety controller is same `<%: Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home"); %>`

Comment: Its not working `<%: Html.ActionLink("Anxiety", "Anxiety", "Anxiety"); %>` home is working now @Chris Pratt

Comment: This will try to render the route for `AxietyController.Anxiety`. However, currently, your controller is named `_AnxietyController`. So that's one problem. The best solution here is to just remove the underscore from your classes. Then, of course, you'll actually need an `Anxiety` action in that controller. If you don't have an action named exactly like that, it won't work either.

Comment: Also, FWIW, this is pretty much MVC 101. I'd recommend stepping back and educating yourself a bit more if you're having problems with something as basic as this. Check out the tutorials on http://www.asp.net/mvc.